# Photoshop create temporary folders not in \Temp

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop

I installed PS on `C:\`, but temp folders are creating on `D:\`, by the way, system `TMP` and `Temp` paths are in `D:\Temp`. How can I fix that? I'd always delete those temp folders manually.

Comment: Type this Command as admin:: `setx Temp C:\Users\username\Appdata\Local\Temp /M`. This set the environment variable to default. Repeat this command with TMP also.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening probably because the location of the TEMP folder is incorrectly configured.

1. If this happens only in Photoshop, then look through the settings of Photoshop, and find something related to TEMP and change that to

   ```
   C:\Windows\Temp
   ```
2. If all apps are storing their temporary files in D drive, then it's because the path is incorrectly set. Follow the steps below to fix that:

(I am not allowed to embed pics cuz I'm a new user, so please click on the links of the pics and see them. Open then in a new tab)

[searching for path settings (pic. Click the link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2wWg.png)

It does no matter if you are on windows 7 or 8, type 'path' in the start menu and the option will pop up. Click on 'settings' under the search bar, if you're on Win8. Select the option with text 'Edit the system environment variables'(highlighted with cursor in the pic above)

[Editing path variables  (pic. Click the link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbfc2.png)

A small window with title 'System Proprties' should pop up (The window on the right in the pic above). Click the button at the very bottom of the window, which is labelled 'Enviromnemt Variables'. A new window with title 'Environment Variables' should pop up. (the left one in the pic)

There you will see two categories - 'User variables for [your user name]' ('Snehit in my case') and the second catrgory will be 'System variables'. In the user variables category (marked '1' in the pic) click on 'TEMP' and click on edit.

In the 'Variable value' paste the following thing.

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Click on 'ok' and edit the 'TMP' value paste the same thing in its value as you just did for 'TEMP'

In the 'System variables' category, find 'TEMP' and 'TMP' from the list(Scroll down) and change both their values to the below path.

```
C:\Windows\TEMP
```

Click on ok on the Environment Variables window and on the system properties window. Reboot your computer and delete the TEMP and TMP folder in D drive.

This should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't helped.

Comment: @Tarasovych Could you pls tell about any other problems or errors related to the Temp folder you get? Also pls tell if the system temp folder path is correctly set or not (I've told how to correct that, in the answer)

Comment: Temp doesn't have any problems with other programs except PS. Now I couldn't save `.psd` as `.png` - new issue. I think reinstalling Windows could solve my problem but I don't do it right now.